# R - Reticulate won't convert numpy array to matrix

Tags: python, arrays, r, matrix, reticulate

In R using Reticulate I create a numpy array like so:

```
> library(reticulate)
> np <- import("numpy")
> np$array(c(1,2,3))
[1. 2. 3.]
```

However, I cannot convert it back to a vector.

```
> py_to_r(np$array(c(1,2,3)))
[1. 2. 3.]
```

I experience this problem whenever I deal with numpy through Reticulate. Is there any way for me to convert my Python arrays back to R matrices or vectors?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this problem?

Comment: From my research it looks like this is specific to conda installations on windows

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you import `numpy` via `import("numpy")`. The Python objects will be automatically converted to their R equivalent.

This should work (note the `convert = FALSE` below):

```
np <- import("numpy", convert = FALSE)
py_to_r(np$array(c(1,2,3)))
```